# .NET Excel Interop- Code stops after file open

Tags: .net, excel, interop

I have worked with .Net excel integration a number of times before but have never seen this sort of behavior. As soon as I call the Open method in the Wookbooks Collection object all future code fails to execute in the sub. The thread appears to hang on the excel application, however the application UI is not frozen (nor excel).

```
If(System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\MaterialCatalog.xlsx")) Then

        Dim excelApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        excelApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        excelApp.Visible = True

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Console.Out.Write("this appears in console")
        Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\MaterialCatalog.xlsx"

        wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
        Console.Out.Write("past") 'continue other code
```

The console will write "this appears in console" but NOT "past". Any ideas why this might be hanging?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I raised the scope of the excel object.

instead of: Dim excelApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

I made it public and declared it outside the Subroutine.